# React Buttons and State - how to avoid too many States?

Tags: reactjs, button, react-hooks, onclick, state

I am still somewhat of a novice to React with much to learn. At the moment I am trying to make a page displaying lightsabers and hilts from Star Wars by clicking a button to show the ones you want. I am doing this by using State, which by the amount of states I currently have seems like the wrong way of doing it.

Here's how I'm doing it: I set a State and put an onClick event that sets the chosen hilt/color to true and the rest to false whilst also rendering information of said hilt/color. It looks like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as QuiGon } from './qui-gon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ObiWan } from './obi-wan.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ObiWanOld } from './obi-hilt-old.svg';
import { ReactComponent as DarthMaul } from './darth-maul-hilt.svg';
import { ReactComponent as AhsokaHilt } from './ahsoka-hilt.svg';
import { ReactComponent as AnakinHilt } from './anakin-hilt.svg';
import { ReactComponent as VaderHilt } from './darth-vader-hilt.svg';
import { ReactComponent as KyloHilt } from './kylo-ren-hilt.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  
  const [nonChosen, setNonChosen] = useState(true);
  const [blue, setBlue] = useState(false);
  const [red, setRed] = useState(false);
  const [green, setGreen] = useState(false);
  const [purple, setPurple] = useState(false);
  const [yellow, setYellow] = useState(false);
  const [white, setWhite] = useState(false);

  const [saberOne, setSaberOne] = useState(true);
  const [doubleSaber, setDoubleSaber] = useState(false);
  const [quiGon, setQuiGon] = useState(false);
  const [obiWanNew, setObiWanNew] = useState(false);
  const [obiWanOld, setObiWanOld] = useState(false);
  const [ahsoka, setAhsoka] = useState(false);
  const [anakinHilt, setAnakinHilt] = useState(false);
  const [vaderHilt, setVaderHilt] = useState(false);
  const [kyloHilt, setKyloHilt] = useState(false);


  return (
    <div className="App">

          {/* Colors */}

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setGreen(true); setWhite(false); setYellow(false); setPurple(false); setRed(false); setBlue(false); setNonChosen(false);}}>Green
          </button> 

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setBlue(true); setWhite(false); setYellow(false); setPurple(false); setRed(false); setGreen(false); setNonChosen(false);}}>Blue
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setRed(true); setWhite(false); setYellow(false); setPurple(false); setBlue(false); setGreen(false); setNonChosen(false);}}>Red
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setPurple(true); setWhite(false); setYellow(false); setGreen(false);  setRed(false); setBlue(false); setNonChosen(false);}}>Purple
          </button> 

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setYellow(true); setWhite(false); setPurple(false); setGreen(false);  setRed(false); setBlue(false); setNonChosen(false);}}>Yellow
          </button> 

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setWhite(true); setYellow(false); setPurple(false); setGreen(false);  setRed(false); setBlue(false); setNonChosen(false);}}>White
          </button> 
          
          <br />

          {/* Hilts */}

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setDoubleSaber(true); setKyloHilt(false); setVaderHilt(false); setAnakinHilt(false); setAhsoka(false); setSaberOne(false); setQuiGon(false); setObiWanNew(false); setObiWanOld(false);}}>Darth Maul
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setQuiGon(true); setKyloHilt(false); setVaderHilt(false); setAnakinHilt(false); setAhsoka(false); setDoubleSaber(false); setSaberOne(false); setObiWanNew(false); setObiWanOld(false);}}>Qui Gon
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setObiWanNew(true); setKyloHilt(false); setVaderHilt(false); setAnakinHilt(false); setAhsoka(false); setDoubleSaber(false); setSaberOne(false); setQuiGon(false); setObiWanOld(false);}}>Obi Wan
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setObiWanOld(true); setKyloHilt(false); setVaderHilt(false); setAnakinHilt(false); setAhsoka(false); setDoubleSaber(false); setSaberOne(false); setQuiGon(false); setObiWanNew(false);}}>Obi Wan Old
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setAhsoka(true); setKyloHilt(false); setVaderHilt(false); setAnakinHilt(false); setObiWanOld(false); setDoubleSaber(false); setSaberOne(false); setQuiGon(false); setObiWanNew(false);}}>Ahsoka Tano
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setAnakinHilt(true); setKyloHilt(false); setVaderHilt(false); setAhsoka(false); setObiWanOld(false); setDoubleSaber(false); setSaberOne(false); setQuiGon(false); setObiWanNew(false);}}>Anakin
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setVaderHilt(true); setKyloHilt(false); setAnakinHilt(false); setAhsoka(false); setObiWanOld(false); setDoubleSaber(false); setSaberOne(false); setQuiGon(false); setObiWanNew(false);}}>Vader
          </button>

          <button className="testsub" onClick={() => { setKyloHilt(true);setVaderHilt(false); setAnakinHilt(false); setAhsoka(false); setObiWanOld(false); setDoubleSaber(false); setSaberOne(false); setQuiGon(false); setObiWanNew(false);}}>Kylo
          </button>


<div class="lightsaber">
  <input type="checkbox" id="on-off" />
          {nonChosen && (
            <>
            <div className="blade colol"></div>
            {/* <div className="blade2 colol"></div> */}
            </>
          )}

          {blue && (
          <div className="blade colol2"></div>
          )}

          {red && (
          <div className="blade red-clr"></div>
          )}

          {green && (
          <div className="blade colol"></div>
          )}

          {purple && (
          <div className="blade purple-clr"></div>
          )}

          {yellow && (
          <div className="blade yellow-clr"></div>
          )}

          {white && (
          <div className="blade white-clr"></div>
          )}


        {saberOne && (
              <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <QuiGon />
            </label>
          )}

        {doubleSaber && (
          <>
            <div className="blade2 colol"></div>
            <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <DarthMaul />
            </label>
            </>
          )}

        {quiGon && (
              <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <QuiGon />
            </label>
          )}

        {obiWanNew && (
              <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <ObiWan />
            </label>
          )}

        {obiWanOld && (
              <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <ObiWanOld />
            </label>
          )}

        {ahsoka && (
              <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <AhsokaHilt />
            </label>
          )}

        {anakinHilt && (
              <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <AnakinHilt />
            </label>
          )}

        {vaderHilt && (
              <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <VaderHilt />
            </label>
          )}

        {kyloHilt && (
            //   <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
            //   <KyloHilt className="hilt2"/>
            // </label>
            <>
            <div className="blade3 colol"></div>
            <div className="blade4 colol"></div>
            <label className="hilt" for="on-off">
              <KyloHilt className="hilt2"/>
            </label>
            </>
          )}

</div>


<div className="infobox">
          {nonChosen && (
            <div>Yoyoyo</div>
          )}

          {blue && (
          <div>aasdsd</div>
          )}

          {green && (
          <div>fgfgfg</div>
          )}

</div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It is not completed hence a bit messy, but the problem shows quite nice. I have a lot of States and the buttons gets quite long with all the setX(false).

Is there any way to do this in a better way? I've been pondering for a long time about doing it pure CSS, with if/else etc. but I can't seem to wrap my head around how go get the button to display one thing and leave the rest hidden without having to over-specify it like I already am. Again I am still a novice, so any help would really be appreciated (and again sorry for the spaghetti code)!

Comment: Why don't you just keep the current selection in the state and nothing else?

Comment: I thought about that, making some sort of "active" state. But wouldn't that keep the chosen image/color active and overlapping when choosing another image/color?

Comment: If it doesn't overlap in your current implementation it should not overlap using only the active selection either.

Comment: Hmm, how would it look in writing if you were to do it? In a way so it won't overlap

Comment: How would you make it to overlap, to begin with? can you make an simple example on codesandbox or similar?

Comment: I think I don't understand how it would inactivate the prior chosen color/image when the new one would be activated

Comment: Only one can be active at the time, I don't see where the problem can come from, if you have conditions like `if (currentColour === 'green') (something green)if (currentColour === 'blue') (something blue)`, how can they overlap?

Comment: Ah, yeah you're right that would not cause overlap. In your example you'd want the state to be changed to 'green' or whatever chosen color instead of a true/false?

Comment: Try to do something of this kind https://jsfiddle.net/joq3gk0n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the values in an object and use them as initial state

```
const initialValues = {
        nonChosen: true,
        blue: false,
        red: false,
        green: false,
        purple: false,
        yellow: false,
        white: false,
        // All other states in this or create a seperate object with seperate useState according to your wish
};
```

And initialize the state as

```
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(initialValues);
```

Setting the value during onClick as

```
  <button className="testsub" onClick={() => {setColors({...colors,green:true,white:false,yellow:false,purple:false,red:false,blue:false,nonchosen:false})>Green</button>
```

During rendering:

```
{colors.nonChosen && (
            <>
            <div className="blade colol"></div>
            {/* <div className="blade2 colol"></div> */}
            </>
  )}
```

Comment: Cool, this does indeed make it more compact, and lessen the need of a lot of states! A lot of nearly-identical buttons but I guess that is hard to get around. Ill try this out for sure!

Comment: Sadly I cannot get this to work :( It throws a lot of not defined errors at me

Comment: @Dannie Can you add the updated code in the question?

Comment: It's the same error as I got in the other answer; it won't recognize the values within the const. So all the true/false values is marked as undefined. I can throw a link to Github with the code that throws undefined if it is permitted to do so?

Comment: @Dannie Yes please

Comment: Hah, funny thing. When I was writing up an example I actually got it to work! I think I've must have forgotten a line or two somewhere initially. It works now, and is a lot shorter than initially! Very cool. Thanks for showing me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use useReducer hook.
Also, you can inline event (for color) or callback event (for hilt).
I used two cases.

```
const initialColorState = {
  nonChosen: false,
  blue: false,
  red: false,
  green: false,
  purple: false,
  yellow: false,
  white: false,
};

const initialHiltState = {
  saberOne: false,
  doubleSaber: false,
  quiGon: false,
  obiWanNew: false,
  obiWanOld: false,
  ahsoka: false,
  anakinHilt: false,
  vaderHilt: false,
  kyloHilt: false
}

function colorReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Blue": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialColorState,
        blue: true,
      }
    }
    case "Red": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialColorState,
        red: true,
      }
    }
    case "Green": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialColorState,
        green: true,
      }
    }
    case "Purple": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialColorState,
        purple: true,
      }
    }
    case "Yellow": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialColorState,
        yellow: true,
      }
    }
    case "White": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialColorState,
        white: true,
      }
    }
  }
}

function hiltReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DoubleSaber": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        doubleSaber: true,
      }
    }
    case "QuiGon": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        quiGon: true,
      }
    }
    case "ObiWanNew": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        obiWanNew: true,
      }
    }
    case "ObiWanOld": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        obiWanOld: true,
      }
    }
    case "Ahsoka": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        ahsoka: true,
      }
    }
    case "Anakin": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        anakinHilt: true,
      }
    }
    case "Vader": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        vaderHilt: true,
      }
    }
    case "Kylo": {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialHiltState,
        kyloHilt: true,
      }
    }
  }
}

function App() {
  const [colorState, colorDispatch] = useReducer(colorReducer, initialColorState)
  const [hiltState, hiltDispatch] = useReducer(hiltReducer, initialHiltState);

  const onHiltClick = useCallback((event) => {
    hiltDispatch({type: event.value});
  }, [hiltDispatch]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Colors */}

      <button
        className="testsub"
        onClick={() => {
          colorDispatch({ type: "Green" })
        }}
      >
        Green
      </button>

      <button
        className="testsub"
        onClick={() => {
          colorDispatch({ type: "Blue" })
        }}
      >
        Blue
      </button>

      <button
        className="testsub"
        onClick={() => {
          colorDispatch({ type: "Red" })
        }}
      >
        Red
      </button>

      <button
        className="testsub"
        onClick={() => {
          colorDispatch({ type: "Purple" })
        }}
      >
        Purple
      </button>

      <button
        className="testsub"
        onClick={() => {
          colorDispatch({ type: "Yellow" })
        }}
      >
        Yellow
      </button>

      <button
        className="testsub"
        onClick={() => {
          colorDispatch({ type: "White" })
        }}
      >
        White
      </button>

      <br />

      {/* Hilts */}

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="DoubleSaber">
        Darth Maul
      </button>

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="QuiGon">
        Qui Gon
      </button>

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="ObiWanNew">
        Obi Wan
      </button>

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="ObiWanOld">
        Obi Wan Old
      </button>

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="Ahsoka">
        Ahsoka Tano
      </button>

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="Anakin">
        Anakin
      </button>

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="Vader">
        Vader
      </button>

      <button className="testsub" onClick={onHiltClick} value="Kylo">
        Kylo
      </button>

      .....
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! When I try this method I get a non defined on all the states, not sure why

Comment: I've updated the code.
Please try it again.

Comment: Still the same error. It won't recognize 'em. Even tried putting everything within the function App( ), doesn't change anything. can it be because it's a functional component and not a class component?